# Trying an easy Form in angular 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript

im trying to make the functionality in the submit botton of an easy AngularJs 2 example. But im not able to find the way to do it.

this is my app.component.html

```
<h1>
    {{title}}
</h1>

<h2>Contactos</h2>

<app-lista-contactos [listaContactos]="contactos" (seleccion)="onSelect($event)">
</app-lista-contactos>

<h2>Detalles</h2>
<app-detalle-contacto [(contacto)]="contactoSeleccionado" (reset)="limpiar()" (guardar)="onSubmit()">
</app-detalle-contacto>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Persona } from './Persona';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Agenda';
  contactos: Persona[] = [
    {name: 'Pedro', email: 'pedro@gmail.com'},
    {name: 'Maria', email: 'maria@gmail.com'},
    {name: 'Juan', email: 'juan@gmail.com'}];

    contactoSeleccionado: Persona = new Persona();
    nuevoContacto = true;

    onSelect(contacto: Persona): void {
      this.contactoSeleccionado = contacto;
      this.nuevoContacto = false;
    }

    onSubmit(): void {
      if (this.nuevoContacto) {
        this.contactos.push(this.contactoSeleccionado);
        this.limpiar();
      }else {
        console.log('Contacto actualizado');
        console.log(this.contactoSeleccionado);
      }
    }

    limpiar(): void {
      this.contactoSeleccionado = new Persona();
      this.nuevoContacto = true;
    }

}
```

persona.ts

```
export class Persona {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}
```

detalle-contacto.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #formulario="ngForm">
    <label id="nameID">Nombre</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="contacto.name" name="name" id="nameID" required>
    <label id="emailID">Email</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="contacto.email" name="email" id="emailID" required>
    <button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()" [disabled]="!formulario.form.valid">Guardar</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="limpiar()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

and detalle-contacto.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Persona } from '../persona';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detalle-contacto',
  templateUrl: './detalle-contacto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detalle-contacto.component.css']
})
export class DetalleContactoComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  contacto: Persona = new Persona();

  @Output()
  reset = new EventEmitter<void>();
  guardar = new EventEmitter<Persona>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  limpiar(): void {
    this.reset.emit();
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    this.guardar.emit();
  }

}
```

I know there should be a lot of mistakes, because i dont understand 100% the binding concept. Also, i dont how really implement the submit functionality in Angular.

I would be glad to receive any help or advice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you make the submit button of `Type="Submit"` and put an `OnSubmit()` in your component, it will work with no more setup. I did it like this:

in the HTML:

```
<button type="submit" label="Submit"></button>
```

in the component:

```
onSubmit() {
   //whatever you want to do codewise here.
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that im using "contactoSelecciondo" for adding dinamically a new Person in the list. 

The onSubmit function in the detalle-contacto.component.ts cant see the variables of the parent component app.component.html. 

As i understand, i should make an event, pass him the information about the new Person and do the binding in the html. Maybe im wrong, and if im right, i dont really know how to implement the functionality.